# Pine Editor Last Value

Tags: pine-script

```
isCloseNearBKR = abs(close - BKR) / BKR * 100 <= 10

lineecolor = isCloseNearBKR ? color.blue : color.red

plot(LINEE, title="LINEE", color=lineecolor)
```

In the pine editor, if the last close value is within 10% of the BKR variable, the line color of the LINEE value should be blue; if it is not within 10%, the line color for the LINEE value should be red. Depending on the last bar value, the entire LINEE line should be red or blue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlTJc.png)

I tried but my LINEE line color changes, I dont want this, if last close value is within %10 all line color must be same, blue or red

Comment: it is not possible, you can't change series calculated in the past bars depending on the current time